# Jquery modal popup not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The popup works when I use it alone like with an input button. But when there is additional code it stops working.  Here is the code for the popup:

```
function kopen() {
    $('#MyDialog').html("<body id='boot'><canvas id='myCanvas' width='350' height='100'></canvas></body>");
    myCanvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    ctx1 = myCanvas.getContext('2d');
    $("#MyDialog").dialog({
        modal : true,
        height : 250,
        width : 505,
        open : function (event, ui) {
            $(this).closest('.ui-dialog').find('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close').hide();
        },
        autoOpen : true
        // ^^^^^^^^^^^
    });
}
```

Comment: Eww, adding `<body>` to dialog element.

Comment: A full code listing(relevant parts) can be found at https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=3GzfcMHr1a

Comment: Why do you have a body tag inside of it?

Comment: Initially I thought I could change the background color with it. But I know now I can do that with CSS. I just didn't remove it.